# How to process Multi Chekboxes in a specific php way

Tags: php

I'm nearly at the end of my multi-step form coding, but I'm having a little trouble processing my form in PHP, especially my checkboxes.

Here's my code, I have 8 checkboxes like these:

```
   <label for="word"  ><img class="img" src="images/my1.jpg"  /></label>
                                        <input type="checkbox" class="chk"   name="ltype[]" id="ltype" value="word" required /><hr> <center><p><strong>Word Mark Logo</strong><br></p></center>
                                   </div>

                                   <div class="thumb1" >
                                         <label for="letter"><img class="img" src="images/my2.jpg"  /></label>
                                         <input type="checkbox" class="chk"   name="ltype[]"   id="ltype"value="letter" /><hr> <center><p><strong>Letter Mark Logo</strong></p></center>
                                   </div>

                                   <div class="thumb1">
                                          <label for="emblerm"><img class="img" src="images/my3.jpg"  /></label>
                                          <input type="checkbox" class="chk"   name="ltype[]" id="ltype" value="emblerm" /><hr> <center><p><strong>Emblerm Logo</strong><br></p></center>
                                   </div>

                                   <div class="thumb1">
                                          <label for="pictorial"><img class="img" src="images/my4.jpg"  /></label>
                                          <input type="checkbox" class="chk"   name="ltype[]" id="ltype" value="pictorial" /><hr> <center><p><strong>Pictorial Mark Logo</strong> </p></center>
                                   </div><br>
```

And my PHP:

```
 <?php
if( isset($_POST['name']) )
{
    $to = 'myemail@gmail.com';  
    $subject = 'NEWLOGO CLIENT FORM'; 
    $headers = 'From: ' . $_POST['email'] . "\r\n" . 'Reply-To: ' . $_POST['email'];    

    $message = 'Name: ' . $_POST['name'] . "\n" .
               'Surname: ' . $_POST['surname'] . "\n" .
               'E-mail: ' . $_POST['email'] . "\n" .
               'Phone: ' . $_POST['phone']. "\n" .
                'Slogan : ' . $_POST['slogan']. "\n" .
                   'Logo pack Chosed : ' . $_POST['emotion']. "\n" .
                   'Logo Color : ' . $_POST['logocolor']. "\n" .
                   'Designers experiment with other colors : ' . $_POST['radio-inline3']. "\n" .
                    'Logo Type : ' . $_POST['ltype']. "\n";     

    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);    
    if( $_POST['copy'] == 'on' )
    {
        mail($_POST['email'], $subject, $message, $headers);
    }
}
?>
```

When I process this, I get : `Logo Type : Array`. What should I do? I'm not yet very familiar with PHP.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's right you have an array, so implode it:

```
'Logo Type : ' . implode(',', $_POST['ltype']). "\n";
```

Comment: Thank you very much , i searched today forever over the internet and i always got it  somehow wrong with this in the first try it worked like charm , have an amazing day wherever you are dude  ;)

Answer (score 0):

With thanks to user "mada" this problem is solved
How to get values from checkboxes in this specific php code structure :

```
<?php
if( isset($_POST['name']) )
{
    $to = 'myemail@gmail.com';  
    $subject = 'NEWLOGO CLIENT FORM'; 
    $headers = 'From: ' . $_POST['email'] . "\r\n" . 'Reply-To: ' . $_POST['email'];    

    $message = 'Name: ' . $_POST['name'] . "\n" .
               'Surname: ' . $_POST['surname'] . "\n" .
               'E-mail: ' . $_POST['email'] . "\n" .
               'Phone: ' . $_POST['phone']. "\n" .
                'Slogan : ' . $_POST['slogan']. "\n" .
                   'Logo pack Chosed : ' . $_POST['emotion']. "\n" .
                   'Logo Color : ' . $_POST['logocolor']. "\n" .
                   'Designers experiment with other colors : ' . $_POST['radio-inline3']. "\n" .
                    'Logo Type : ' . $_POST['ltype']. "\n";

    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);    
    if( $_POST['copy'] == 'on' )
    {
        mail($_POST['email'], $subject, $message, $headers);
    }
}
?>
```

In html you have to put the specific section of chekboxes you want the same name with these brackets example

```
  <input type="checkbox" class="chk"   name="ltype[]"   id="ltype" value="letter" /><hr> <center><p><strong>Letter Mark Logo</strong></p></center>
                                   </div>
```

like this `name="ltype[]"`

and again in php to implode the values:

```
'Logo Type : ' . implode(',', $_POST['ltype']). "\n";
```

and you finally will we get all the values of checked checkboxes